# Variable steps in asp.net ajax multiple slider control

Tags: asp.net, html, ajax, slider

I am having an asp.net slider

```
<asp:TextBox ID="sliderTwo" runat="server" Style="display: none;" />
<ajaxToolkit:MultiHandleSliderExtender ID="multiHandleSliderExtenderTwo" runat="server" BehaviorID="multiHandleSliderExtenderTwo" TargetControlID="sliderTwo" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Length="175" TooltipText="{0}" Orientation="Vertical" EnableHandleAnimation="true" EnableKeyboard="false" EnableMouseWheel="false" ShowHandleDragStyle="true" ShowHandleHoverStyle="true">
    <MultiHandleSliderTargets>
        <ajaxToolkit:MultiHandleSliderTarget ControlID="multiHandle2_1_BoundControl" />
        <ajaxToolkit:MultiHandleSliderTarget ControlID="multiHandle2_2_BoundControl" />
    </MultiHandleSliderTargets>
</ajaxToolkit:MultiHandleSliderExtender>
```

It has the values - 1,2,3, ... 100 but I want to have values -> 1,5,10,20,50,100,200,500,1000.

Comment: What do you want to do with these values? Do you need them in code behind or do you want to display them as you slide?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Minimum an maximum value as below but you cant set specific values for points on the slider. You can use the `Steps` attribute to miss numbers in the range but these steps are consistent.

```
Minimum="1" Maximum="1000" Steps="5"
```

However if specifically want only want the following 9 values (1,5,10,20,50,100,200,500,1000) you could set the slider to have 9 points `Minimum="1" Maximum="9"` and have logic (either client side or server side) which knows e.g. if the slider equals 3 then its 10 on your scale.

```
1 = 1
2 = 5
3 = 10
...
9 = 1000
```